# Javascript can't finish code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

When user scroll and

> navmenu

come to

> margin-top 20px

, then the menu will stop and be fixed. How i can to that? navmenu is Div id of my menu. I try all ways and I can not figure out.

Here is code that i need ...

```
$("navmenu").scrollTop(function () {
    var height = $("navmenu").scrollTop();
    alert(height);
    if (height > 20) {
        /* need help here */
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng3Hu/)

This works on scrolling on the page itself, you may want to adjust if you're referring to scrolling  specific element.

CSS

```
#navmenu {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
    position:relative;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $('#navmenu').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
        $('#navmenu').css('position', 'relative');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> navmenu is Div id of my menu

The selector `navmenu` will match `<navmenu>` elements (which do not exist in HTML).

You want `#navmenu`.